# In TypeScript supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Tags: angular, typescript

In JavaScript we can call a function based on the number of parameter we passed remaining it will take as **undefined** without any error it will work. Please refer to the below snippet for reference.

```js
function test(a,b){
  if(b){console.log(b)}
  else{console.log('b is undefined')}
  console.log(a)
}
test(5);
test(5,6);
```

In angular2 I have service called `DataWrapperService`:

```js
export class DataWrapperService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  
  getData (URL,interval): Observable<any> {
    if(interval){
      return Observable
      .interval(interval)
      .flatMap(() => return this.http.get(URL)
                .map(this.extractData)
    }else{
     return this.http.get(URL)
                .map(this.extractData)
     }
  }
  private extractData (res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

}
```

And I am using the datawrapper service in my test component.

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataWrapper : DataWrapperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getTestData();
  }

  getTestData() {
   this.dataWrapper.getData("http://localhost/test").subscribe(data => this.handleTestData(data)
  }

  handleTestData(data) {
   console.log(data)
  }

}
```

When I tried to call `getData` passing only one parameter as url TypeScript throws the error **supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target**.

Comment: Just read the [manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer (not only because it's the only answer but also because it answers your question)

Answer (score 1):

To make a function parameter optional, add a '?' to the argument in the function signature.
ex:

```
func(param1:string, param2?:string) {}
```